# Join ON order in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a question which is similar but not quite the same to others I've seen in on stackoverflow

Let's say I have the following query

```
select * 
from BobsFriends bf 
left outer join JennysFriends jf on bf.friendID = jf.friendID
```

does `bf.friendID = jf.friendID` and `jf.friendID = bf.friendID`  return different results?  I would think that these would return the same result but

```
select * 
from JennysFriends bf 
left outer join BobsFriends jf on bf.friendID = jf.friendID
```

would return different ones.

Comment: Much like a WHERE clause, the order of comparisons in the ON clause has no effect on the results.

Answer (score 3):

The order of the columns when comparing for the JOIN doesn't matter, but when doing an `OUTER JOIN` the order of the tables definitely matters.

For a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` you are going to always get the results from the *first* table, with data from the second table, if available.

For a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` you are always going to get the results from the *second* table, with data from the first table, if available.

Comment: thanks. I was pretty sure but a coworker seemed pretty convinced I was wrong

Comment: I know people that will argue the *aesthetics* of which column you should put first, but you'll get the same results either way.

Comment: @KillerSmalls Maybe they are really old school. With the old style of joins (ie. "* =" or "= *"), the order mattered.

Answer (score 0):

`Left outer join` produces a complete set of records from Table A (the "left side" table), with the matching records (where available) in Table B (the "right side" one). If there is no match, the right side will contain null.